# How can I capture NgbTypeahead SelectedItemEvent?

Tags: angular, typeahead, ng-bootstrap

I want to run some custom logic on item selection from typeahead. I am unable to bind selected item event with typeahead control. I am using ng-bootstrap (bootstrap4).

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" placeholder="Search" [resultTemplate]="rt"  [inputFormatter]="formatter" />
```

Comment: You did try `(selectItem)="someFunction($event)"`?

Answer (score 13):

You can bind to the selectItem output of the ngbTypeahead

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (selectItem)="itemSelected($event)" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt" [inputFormatter]="formatter" />
```

This would go in your component class:

```
itemSelected($event) {
    alert($event.item.name);
  }
```

Here is a working plunker: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/o0EPMzv4VvI0R9LbhjJr?p=preview)

Comment: You can also use standard Angular protocol and separate out [(ngModel)] into [ngModel] and (ngModelChange)